# Export to PNG produces wrong color background (but not for JPG)

Tags: arcmap, export, color, png, data-frame

I need to export a map as a PNG image, but when I do the background, which is supposed to be white, comes out gray. This also happens when I export it as a TIFF or EMF, but not as a JPG.

I have tried different combinations of putting white vs no color as the data frame color and as "background color" option when exporting (see attached images comparing JPG and PNG). Any suggestions?

[image: Correct image]
[image: image as PNG (wrong background color)]

Comment: See : https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000008725

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that before and it didn't work. Anyway, according to that article, this should be a problem with JPEGs but not PNGs. For me it's the other way around.